# Using InterstitialAd with InterstitialAdListener. Getting Error Message

Tags: java, android, facebook-audience-network

I am getting this error when using `InterstitialAdListener`

```
 Anonymous class derived from InterstitialAdListener' must either be declared > abstract or implement abstract method 'onInterstitialDismissed(Ad) in 
'InterstitialAdListener'
```

The `InterstitialAdListener` is red color underlined.

I tried reduced it to `com.facebook.ads.AdListener` but doesn't work with me Also, I upgrade SDK to see if it would solve it but didn't have luck.

How I can solve this problem ?

```
    private void initInterstitialAdPrepare() {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx");
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {

                    @Override
                public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                    // Interstitial ad displayed callback
                    Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad displayed.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                    // Ad error callback
                    Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
                }



                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                    // Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
                    Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");


                    }

                    // Show the ad
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Call this in onCreate**

```
private void requestInterstitialAd(){
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_id)); //YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID
    interstitialAd.loadAd();
}
```

Use this code where you want to load ad and for splash use it once your splash timer is completed

```
if(interstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) {
        interstitialAd.show();
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                requestInterstitialAd();
                //Perform your functionality here
            }
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {

            }
        });
    }
    else {
        requestInterstitialAd();
        //Perform your functionality here in case ad is not loaded before
    }
```